# How does one 'correct' a table that doesn't add up to $100\%$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a table consisting of a number of *whole* percentages $x_i$ between $0\%$ and $100\%$. However, they don't add up to $100\%$ (rather they add up to $101\%$). But they 'should'.

Assuming that any given percentage $x_i\%$ is rounded from some *precise* (unrounded) $y_i\%$ which is *really* uniformly distributed according to $y_i\sim \text{UNIF}(\max{(x_i-0.5\%,0\%)},\min(x_i+0.5\%,100\%))$, what is the best way to go about computing some estimates for unrounded $y_i$s, i.e. $\text{E}(y_i)$? I prefer expectation (over MLE).

NB: The table does contain some $x_i=0\%$ entries.

NB 2: The $\text{E}(y_i)$s that I am looking for are reals, not integers.

NB 3: Simply *scaling* doesn't work. For example take $10\%$, $80\%$ and $11\%$. Total $101\%$. Just scaling those down would obviously yield $100\%$. But $80\%\cdot \frac{100\%}{101\%}=79.2079\ldots\%$ will now round to $79\%$ instead of $80\%$. So, this cannot be right.

NB 4: Distributing the error equally over all entries has a drawback too. If the error would be $−1\%$, some such $\text{E}(y_i)$s (e.g. those belonging to $x_i=0$) could become *less than zero*. That indicates that that procedure cannot be right either.

Comment: The $0$% entries would end up with the greatest amount of relative change (i.e., $\infty$), and are thus the ones that are most affected by having rounding applied to them.  Is there any system that allows this as a reasonable outcome?

Comment: "Should" according to whom? Are you just fudging your data to assuage the stupid people in your audience who don't understand rounding?

Comment: If you ask three persons for some opinion, you might get $33\,\%$ for eac of the answers "yes", "no", "maybe". And now you want to forcefully break the tie by claiminng that one of the answers really got $34\,\%$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have this table and I want to work with it. But with it not adding up to $100\%$ that leads to problems. Therefore I want to fix that first.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, the $y$s are precise. In that example they would all be $100/3\%$.

Comment: Youer model seems to accpt that the "simulated true" $2$ becomes negative if $x=0$?

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat Yeah, but then you cannot end up with $100\,\%$.

Comment: You ask about recovering unrounded $y$s (which you can't do) but really seem concerned about some way to perturb the $x$s so they add to $100$ (which you can only do of you give up having the $x$s be properly rounded from the $y$s)

Comment: @RossMillikan I know I cannot recover the $y$s. But given my assumptions, they could be estimated.

Comment: If the $x$s add to $101$ as here, you know that on average the $x$s are below the $y$s by $\frac 1n$ (where there are $n\ x$ s.)  You could use that to estimate the $y$s as you say.  Whether that is useful, I don't know.  It certainly doesn't help force the sum of the $x$s to $100$

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm fully aware that any $y$s don't change the $x$s. I'm _only_ interested in reasonable estimates of the $y$s. The $x$s stay exactly what they were.

Comment: Why not distribute the error evenly to every value?

Comment: @EmmadKareem Because if the error would be $-1\%$, some $\text{E}(y_i)$s (e.g. those belonging to $x_i=0$) could become less than zero. That indicates that that procedure cannot be right.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat, this makes sense. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compute unrounded $y$s because you have thrown away the information by rounding.  What you can do is to alter the $x$s so they add to $100\%$.  You will then violate the fact that the $x$s are the rounded values closest to the $y$'s.  If they currently add to $101\%$, you just need to decrease one of them by $1\%$.  If you have the $y$s available, you can choose the one that is closest above $zz.50\%$, which seems the logical one to flip-it makes the least error.  If you don't have the $y$s available, I would decrease the largest $x$, just because it introduces the least fractional error.  But you might as well pick one at random.

Comment: Rounding the $y$s should lead, at least, to the given $x$s.

Comment: You can't have both that and have the $x$s add to $100\%$ all the time.  What would you do with $33.6, 33.6, 33.8$?  These round to $34,34,34$, which add to $102$.  That is why many tables have a footnote that the percentages may not add to $100$ due to rounding.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I'm looking for a reasonable way to make the $y$s add up to $100\%$ and still have the rounding correct: that each $y$ rounds to its $x$.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen and I have both given examples showing that you can't both have normal rounding and guarantee the rounded values add to $100$.  In my answer I propose shifting the breakpoint away from the usual $0.5$ to restore the sum.  It would round the two $33.6$s down, giving $33,33,34$.  Ties are a problem, as Hagen's example shows.  I don't know what to do that is sensible there.

Comment: I only want to _reconstruct_ the ('expected') $y$s. Obviously, every $y$ needs to round to its $x$. Also, obviously, because the $y$s are exact, they add up to $100\%$. Why am I failing to bring this point across?

Comment: Take my example.  If all you know is that the $x$s are $34, 34, 34$ how would you know that the third one started out higher?  The original data did add to $100$, but rounding spoiled that and obscured the differences.

Comment: I that case, I would be looking for an answer that gives $100/3\%$ for each. (I'm not interested in 'higher'.)

Comment: You could always estimate $y_i=\frac {x_i}{\sum x_i}$ if your estimates don't have to be whole percents.

Comment: Yes, but I think that in some cases _that_ $\text{E}(y_i)$ won't round to $x_i$ anymore. That's why I came up with the explicit prior distribution.

Comment: For example take $10\%$, $80\%$ and $11\%$. Total $101\%$. Just scaling those down would obviously yield $100\%$. But $80\%\cdot 100/101=79.2079\ldots$ will now round to $79\%$ instead of $80\%$. So, this cannot be right.

Comment: You can reduce all the nonzero ones by the same arithmetic amount.  So in this case you get $9\frac 23 \%, 79 \frac 23 \%, 10 \frac 23 \%$.  Does that do what you want?  They all round properly.  Of course, my $34,34,34$ case fails, as you would reduce them all by $\frac 23 \%$

Answer (score 1):

If you have the unrounded $y_i$ available, you may use algorithms used in elections (to compute party seats from vote counts), such as d'Hondt or Hare-Niemeyer. Essentialy, most methods boil down to finding real numbers $a,b$ such that an assignment of $x_i=\lfloor ay_i+b\rfloor $ yields $\sum x_i=100$. 
Standard rounding sets $b=\frac12$ and $a=\frac{100}{\sum y_i}$ and often fails to meet the goal; other methods stay with $b=\frac12$ but adjust $a$ until the goal is met; or stay with $a=\frac{100}{\sum y_i}$ and adjust $b$; or play with both. Even the best methods will fail in an actual tie. And the choice between methods will influence the outcome in some direction (in election systems: prefer either small or big parties; accordingly with your application), so should be make with care and documented.

Note that after doing any such "correction", the reader of your table may feel satisfied that all adds up to $100\,\%$, but he can never be sure that a value shown as $50\,\%$ is really between $49.5\,\%$ and $50.5\,\%$ - it may certainly lie outsude that interval and have been "forced" to the displayed numbr.

Comment: I don't have the unrounded $y$s available. I want to estimate them. And this is not for election purposes. I only want a reasonable (actually: the most reasonable) unrounded table that rounds to the original one and adds up to $100\%$. Is my question that unclear, I worry.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you're trying to do. Given $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, you have bounds $l_i=\max(x_i−\frac12,0)$ and $u_i=\min(x_i+\frac12,100)$, and you're considering the probability space $[l_1,u_1]\times\cdots\times[l_n,u_n]$ under the additional condition that $y_1+\cdots+y_n=100$. Assuming said space is nonempty, you assign uniform probability density to it and you want to find the expectation of $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$.

This probability space is the intersection of a hypercube and a hyperplane, which forms an $(n-1)$-dimensional polytope, and the expectation is its centroid. I don't know how you would actually compute this in general. But in your problem you almost always have symmetry, and the right solution is just to assign the same absolute change to each entry. Got $101$ instead of $100$? Subtract $1/n$ from all $x_i$. This only fails when one or more of the values are at $0$ or $100$ already.

Comment: Thank you. The first paragraph, I think, captures my problem. However, the problem is that the symmetry (as mentioned in your second paragraph) applies only to numbers from $1$ through $99$. $0$ and $100$ are different. And in the tables that I have to work with, there are $0$s (as mentioned in the question). :(

Comment: Right, so then what you really want is the centroid of the intersection of a hypercube and a hyperplane. As I said, I don't know how to compute that, but maybe if you edit your question to include this characterization of the problem, you might attract the attention of someone who does.

Comment: I could do that, but I must admit that I'm not very familiar with centroids, hypercubes and hyperplanes. That way it might become obvious that I don't know much at all. :) I thought that the question as such must have been thought of by many people. For example those making graphs and pie charts and such.

Comment: @Keepthesemind: It dividing the discrepancy among the entries would cause some to go below $0$ or above $1$, then we don't touch those entries and divide among the other entries instead. My reason is that we want to preserve the relative order of values so it's best to move them in the same general direction.